# Disable the iOS Share Screen for App, when triggered by 'navigator.share()' (Web Share API)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am building an iOS App that uses a WKWebView to provide a Browser. When a web page uses the `navigator.share()` method of the Web Share API, the browser will trigger the iOS Sharing Screen (ShareSheet), where the user can decide how to share the resource.

This App is for kids and we want to disable sharing.

**I have tried:** injecting Javascript into the WebView:

`navigator.share = null;`

This works fine, but not if `navigator.share()` is called from within an iframe. For example YouTube embedded videos with a share link.

**Ideally the solution would be to either:**

1. Disable the iOS Share Screen for this App.
2. Disable `navigator.share` in WKWebView (Swift, Objective-C).

I have searched extensively for a solution, but since the Web Share API is somewhat recent there are not many resources out there.  Thanks!